# How can I select a dynamically limited range of nodes without using non-dynamic positions?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<li></li>
  <th>
<li></li>
  <strong>"Jeff"<strong>
<li></li>
  <a>"Mary"<a>
<li></li>
  <th>
<li></li>
  <strong>"Rich"<strong>
<li></li>
  <strong>"Alex"<strong>
<li></li>
  <a>"Bob"<a>
<li></li>
  <th>
<li></li>
  <strong>"Dave"<strong>
<li></li>
  <a>"Joseph"<a>
<li></li>
  <th>
```

I need to select all the list items that contain "Jeff" and "Mary" by using "Jeff" in an xpath, and without selecting anything else and without using non-dynamic positions.

Example:

```
//li[following-sibling::li/strong[contains(text() , "Jeff")]]/following-sibling::li[th][1]/preceding-sibling::li[not(th)]
```

This works great for the first set(Jeff and Mary), but once applied to ranges further down the code, it falls apart and begins to select more than needed.

Example:

```
//li[following-sibling::li/strong[contains(text() , "Rich")]]/following-sibling::li[th][1]/preceding-sibling::li[not(th)]
```

This selects "Rich", "Alex", "Bob"...but also "Jeff" and "Mary"

Example:

```
//li[following-sibling::li/strong[contains(text() , "Dave")]]/following-sibling::li[th][1]/preceding-sibling::li[not(th)]
```

This selects "Dave" and "Joseph", but also "Rich", "Alex", "Bob", "Jeff" and "Mary".

I want to be able to plug in a name, and have an expression that selects all the list items that are siblings of the list item that contains that name, but also stops selecting once it reaches a list item that contains a header. The problem seems to lie in that the list items with headers are not unique in any way. Is this something that xpaths just cannot do?

Comment: Seems you never did show what you actually do want to select from your example, and your verbal description is too unclear to use.

Comment: @kjhughes I believe OP wants list of -loosely- consecutive names given the first name in the list. So it should be 'Jeff', 'Mary' given 'Jeff'; 'Rich', 'Alex', 'Bob' given 'Rich'; and 'Dave', 'Joseph' given 'Dave'.

Comment: I could be very wrong in guessing where the `</th>` tags should be put though...@GeoffreyCK please clarify. Thanks

Comment: @har07: I'll stand back and applaud your brave interpretation with an upvote on your answer if for no other reason that you made some sort of sense of this question.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your sample HTML is not a well-formed XML i.e many elements are missing closing tags. Consider the following well-formed XML sample adapted from yours :

```
<div> 
  <li/>  
  <th> 
    <li/>  
    <strong>"Jeff"</strong>  
    <li/>  
    <a>"Mary"</a>  
    <li/> 
  </th>  
  <li/>  
  <strong>"Rich"</strong>  
  <li/>  
  <strong>"Alex"</strong>  
  <li/>  
  <a>"Bob"</a>  
  <li/>  
  <th> 
    <li/>  
    <strong>"Dave"</strong>  
    <li/>  
    <a>"Joseph"</a>  
    <li/> 
  </th> 
</div>
```

The following XPath returned the wanted list of text nodes for 'Jeff', 'Rich', and 'Dave' :

```
//li[
    following-sibling::*[1][contains(text(),'put the name here')]
]/following-sibling::*/text()
```

The XPath first looks for `<li>` that is directly followed by element containing the name. Then from the found `<li>`, it return text nodes from within all the following sibling elements.

The XPath would fail, however, if you have another set of names that isn't wrapped in `<th>` (currently you only have one set of such names, which is fine). You can add another logic which counts preceding `<th>`, for example, to handle this case. That will make the XPath fairly complex though, so I won't implement it unless it actually needed.